# Добавление asp.net web api как виртуальную папку в IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

Доброго врмени суток.

Задача такова что нужно поднять 2 веб приложения на одном порте. 
Одно из них asp.net mvc другое asp.net web api. Я создал сайт в IIS и добавил туда наш asp.net mvc приложение, проверил работает.. После этого создал в Корне (IIS) нашего веб приложения, виртуальную дерикторию которой указал путь к asp.net web api приложению и урл - WebApi. MVC -работает а WebApi нет.

Вот такой скрин:
[image]

В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: что-то вы рано сдались

ну попробуйте убрать из web.config в папке с WebApi эту строчку, а настройки аутентификации сделать через IIS Manager - он положит их туда, куда следует

Comment: та не рано. много всяких вариаций перепробовал.. так пробовал не хочет

Comment: или скинте ссылку по похожей теме. Может что не так делаю..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла переустановка IIS